# ось Y только с положительными целыми значениями. Chart.js 3.5 + react-chartjs-2

Tags: chart.js

У меня есть график, который в реальном времени показывает значения Y. Они могут быть только положительными. Проблема в следующем: по умолчанию chart.js строит мне график следующим образом:

[image: График по умолчанию, без доп. опций]

Если я ограничиваю отрицательные значения Y с помощью опций: *min: 0*, то я получаю "обрезанные значения" на графике, как показано ниже:

[image: График с обрезанными значениями]

Единственный раз, когда я получал график с видом как мне нужно был когда я сделал ему ограничение по max y, но оно мне как раз не нужно, но внешний вид мне необходим именно такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание: я не знаю какое значение y может быть максимальное, и просто задать какое то большое значение тоже не вариант. значение y отслеживается в реальном времени, поэтому часто пользователь может видеть график, где все y будут 0.
Мои Options:

```
const LineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                stacked: true,
                max: 1,
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 1,
                },
            },
        },
    };
```

Так же есть ещё 1 **проблема**: после обновления chart.js с 2.х на 3.х цвет подписей к шкалам стал "мыльным", как видно на картинках. Я не могу разобраться, как это исправить.
Должны быть атрибуты на подобии scaleFontColor, scaleLineColor, но не понял куда их нужно прописывать.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Оptions должны выглядеть следующим образом:

```
const LineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 1,
                },
            },
        },
    };
```